# Displaying Blank screen by using cordova-plugin-google maps Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-2

am new to using cordova google maps in my ionic app.when used this plugin in my app am getting blank screen like

[image: blank screen]

I followed  step by step as mentioned in [cordova google maps plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps)

Generated valid google maps API key for Android device

this is the code i worked on it...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

  // Initialize the map view
  map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);

  // Wait until the map is ready status.
  map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
}, false);

function onMapReady() {
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", onBtnClicked, false);
}

function onBtnClicked() {
  map.showDialog();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>PhoneGap-GoogleMaps-Plugin</h3>
 <div style="width:100%;height:400px" id="map_canvas"></div>
 <button id="button">Full Screen</button>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me anyone.

Comment: Please provide minimal code that is creating the problem.

Comment: hi @StephenReindl can you please see once again i updated my Query...